# How to generate or create the largest number from a given array using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate the largest number from a given array using Ruby.

**Example 1**

```
## Input
my_array = %w{8 40 9}

## Expected Output
"9840"
```

**Example 2**

```
## Input
my_array = %w{9 8 40 9}

## Expected Output
"99840"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sort` with a custom comparison block.

`my_array.sort{|a, b| b + a <=> a + b }`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple alphabetical order with expected output:

```
my_array.sort.reverse.join
```

or you can order your array by integers:

```
my_array.map(&:to_i).sort.reverse.map(&:to_s).join
```

Comment: `["1", "10"]` would result in `"101"` instead of `"110"`.

Comment: cause from big to small, delete `.reverse` for expected

Comment: @Stefan I didn't understand from the question if multi digit elements can/should be separated or not.

Comment: @ДаниилМухачёв what about `%w{ 10 1 2 }` – it gives `"2101"` / `"1021"` with your above code and `"1102"` / `"1210"` when deleting `reverse`. None of them is correct: the largest possible combination is `"2110"`

Comment: @Joel_Blum I'd say they should be kept as a unit. You might want to ask the author for clarification.

Comment: @Stefan you're right, i inattentively read the conditions